# Convert three bytes, two's complement, signed integer

Tags: ruby, endianness, signed, twos-complement, 24-bit

In the [SEG-D seismic data format](https://seg.org/Publications/SEG-Technical-Standards), some header parameters are formatted as three bytes, two’s complement, signed binary. All values are big-endian.

Using [String#unpack](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-unpack), Ruby core can only convert 16-bit and 32-bit values, but not 24-bit.

How can I get the binary values converted into integers in the following [two’s complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) way:

```ruby
"\x00\x00\x00" => 0x000000 (0)
"\x00\x00\x01" => 0x000001 (1)
"\x7F\xFF\xFF" => 0x7FFFFF (8388607)
"\xFF\xFF\xFF" => -0x000001 (-1)
"\x80\x00\x00" => -0x800000 (-8388608)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the fist byte as signed 8-bit (two’s complement) and the second and third as unsigned 16-bit.

```ruby
# String to be converted (-8388608)
bin = "\x80\x00\x00"

# Convert as signed 8-bit and unsigned 16-bit (big-endian)
values = bin.unpack("c S>")

# Add with the first byte weighted
converted = values[0] * 2**16 + values[1]
```

Alternate version of the last line using bitwise operations [shift](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Integer.html#method-i-3C-3C) and [OR](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Integer.html#method-i-7C) (probably more efficient):

```
converted = values[0] << 16 | values[1]
```

Comment: I have great respect for anyone who understands `pack/unpack`. I've tried more than once to master it but always give up after a few minutes with a splitting headache. Consider the following tweak: `values[0] << 16 + values[1]`. See [Integer#<<](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Integer.html#method-i-3C-3C).

Comment: @CarySwoveland It is indeed more elegant but I only use `<<` and other bitwise operations in private. They are quite cryptic for beginners. :-)

Comment: If a Rubiest understands `pack/unpack` it's a reasonable assumption that they are aware of `Integer#<<` (as well as the subtleties of metaprogramming).

Comment: @CarySwoveland speaking of subtleties: `(values[0] << 16) + values[1]` ;-)

Comment: @Stefan, I did test, and got the same result, but did not notice that `values[1] #=> 0`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland another option is to use binary OR instead of plus, i.e. `values[0] << 16 | values[1]`. Or `a, b = bin.unpack('c S>')` and `a << 16 | b`. Or for a one-liner `bin.unpack('c S>').yield_self { |a, b| a << 16 | b }`